# Regex to get the first element of each line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the first element of each line, be it either a number or a string but when the line starts with a number, my current attempt still includes it:

```
const totalWords = "===========\n\n  1-test\n\n 2-ests \n\n 1 zfzrf";

const firstWord = totalWords.replace(/\s.*/,'')
```

The output I get :

```
1-test
2-ests 
1 zfzrf
```

The output I would like:

```
1
2 
1
```

Comment: What are you defining as an `element`? Is it a number? Containing a single digit? Any other restrictions?

Comment: What are valid delimiters that separate the first element of a line from the following? From your example I infer, separation is done via space or dash?

Comment: @StefanNeubert yes it's either a space or a dash

Comment: @AndyG a number with a single degit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you are interested in a non-regexp version (should be faster)

```js
var str = "===========\n\n  1-test\n\n 2-ests \n\n 1 zfzrf";

var res = str.split("\n");
for (row of res) {
  let words = row.trim().split(' ');
  let firstWord = words[0].trim();
  // get first character, parse to int, validate it is infact integer
  let element = firstWord.charAt(0);
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(element))) {
    console.log('Row', row);
    console.log('Element: ', element);
  }
}
```

Comment: it return the whole line, i want to get only the first element in each line which in my case are numbers

Comment: Since in a comment it was said that it is single digit I just look at the first non space character of the first word of each row. 

I have edited the code to also console.log the element.

Comment: @tiaranane if possible please accept one of the answers so we can wrap this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex should skip leading spaces and then capture everything until a space or a dash, so you might want to go with `^\s*([^ -]+)`.

(See https://regex101.com/r/u7ELiw/1 for application to your examples)

If you additionally know exactly that you are looking for a single digit, you can instead go for `^\s*(\d)`

(See https://regex101.com/r/IWhEQ1/1 again for applications)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe im not too sure what you are asking but why are you using something as convoluted as regex when

```
line.charAt(0)
```

works pretty well?